# Jenkins on different port rather than 8080 in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, port

I see the option to change Jenkins HTTP port is by passing --httpPort=$HTTP_PORT when Jenkins is started. In Ubuntu the default installation, Jenkins is launched as a daemon up on start. Where do I set -httpPort in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following two lines after DAEMON_ARGS in the file

> /etc/init.d/jenkins

```
HTTP_PORT=8010  <br/>
JENKINS_ARGS="--httpPort=$HTTP_PORT"
```

Answer (score 1):

Check /etc/default/jenkins - it works for Debian, i suppose it's same on Ubuntu

[Installing jenkins on ubuntu](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+on+Ubuntu)